# Consolidate Overlapping Ranges in Oracle Sql query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm looking to solve using SQL query that would consolidate the ranges between records based on a common Category (Event_Name), the requirement is to have the query process all records, and the result is a unique representation of the data set having fewer records and unique ranges.

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

Comment: Why is category A not from 130 to 240? Why are there not 3 rows for Category B as there is not overlap from 502-506?

Comment: Thanks @MT0 made the necessary changes.